# Clases y def en python

Tags: python, class, print

Esto es un poco básico, pero hace tiempo que no ocupo python base, mi duda es la siguiente:
Quiero ejecutar este código que es para detectar números primos, si lo pongo sin clase ni nada funciona, pero cuando lo intente poner en una clase no me responde, este es el código:

```
class Numero():


    def primo():
        numero = 0
        valor = range(2, numero)
        contador = 0
        for n in valor:
            if numero % n == 0:
                contador += 1
                print("divisor:", n)

        if contador > 0:
            print("El número no es primo")
        else:
            print("El nÚmero es primo")

numero = int(input("¿Qué número quieres saber si es primo? "))
miObjeto = Numero()
print(miObjeto)
```

Si pudieran ayudarme estaría muy agradecido!

Comment: `numero` es una variable local dentro de la clase, inicializada en cero. El `numero` que lees desde teclado tiene el mismo nombre, pero no es el mismo objeto. Son dos variables distintas. Opción: pasar `numero` como parámetro a `primo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes unos pequeños errores. Te pongo el código comentado y después te explico de forma mas detallada.

```py
#Creamos la clase
class Numero():
    #Creamos un metodo (Que recibe el parametro self, y el parametro numero)
    def primo(self, numero):

        valor = range(2, numero)
        contador = 0
        for n in valor:
            if numero % n == 0:
                contador += 1
                print("divisor:", n)

        #En este if-else devolvemos un string.
        if contador > 0:
            return "El número no es primo"
        else:
            return "El nÚmero es primo"


numero = int(input("¿Qué número quieres saber si es primo? "))

#Instanciamos un objeto a partir de la clase
miObjeto = Numero()

#Imprimimos por pantalla lo que nos devuelve el metodo del objeto.
print(miObjeto.primo(numero))
```

Empecemos.

- **En la linea 4 `def primo():`**

No estas pasando parámetros y haces la pregunta del numero fuera de la clase, por tanto debes pasar por parámetro el numero.

- **En el bloque if-else de la linea 13 a la 16 `if contador > 0:`**

En este punto yo he optado por usar return y devolver una cadena de texto, pero no es necesario, pero si vas a dejar el print, tienes que borrar el print de la linea 20, ya que no devolvería nada.

- **En la linea 20 `print(miObjeto)`**

En esta linea no solo debes llamar al objeto, sino también al comportamiento que quieras que tenga (al método "primo" en este caso).

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Agradezco infinitamente que se tome el tiempo de explicarme, funciono correctamente y logre entender lo que estaba haciendo mal, muchas gracias!